# Perforce cmd line option to populate workspace

Tags: perforce, workspace, populate

I am new to Perforce and have some experience using ClearCase earlier. I am using a Windows XP client and trying to set up my perforce client/workspace.

The Perforce view I have has mappings of type:
    //depot/path/to/folder/... //my_workspace/depot/path/to/folder/...
However, I have not attempted the "Get latest revision" action (in p4v) for this workspace. That means, I don't have a local copy of the folder in question.

My question is: How do I populate the workspace with contents of the folder from the command line when the folder isn't present in the workspace ? The manual for `p4 sync` talks about getting a certain revision when the file is present in the workspace.

In terms of ClearCase, when the config spec for a snapshot view is having loadrules too, then cleartool can be told to pick the config spec from a text file and also load the contents of the view. I am trying to achieve a similar thing for Perforce.

Thanks in advance,
Parag Doke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the sync command will populate the workspace. If a file or folder isn't already present, it will be created during the sync operation.

With no additional flags specified, `p4 sync` will populate your workspace with the latest contents at the time the command is started.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Turned out that I was making some mistake in typing the command (still some time probably ... before I get conversant with Perforce).